# COPY VALUES, NO FORMULAS. EXCEL VBA

Tags: excel, vba, copy, formulas

I am writting a code to copy a sheet from one workbook(W1) to another workbook(W2).
I know how to do it, but the problem is the copied sheet in W2 still has the formulas and references from W1, and I don't want that I just want the values.

This is my code to copy the sheet:

```
    Set W1 = Workbooks("REPORT1.xlsx")
    Set W2 = Workbooks("REPORT2.xlsx")
    W1.Sheets("TEST").Copy After:=W2.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
```

Any thoughts.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Set W1 = Workbooks("REPORT1.xlsx")
Set W2 = Workbooks("REPORT2.xlsx")
W1.Sheets("TEST").Copy After:=W2.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value
```

Comment: Thanks it work perfectly. Could I use that to graphics as well

Comment: If I can copy some graphics to a new sheet whiout any reference, just the value.

Comment: As far as I know images are copied without any reference. I don't deal with images in excel very often so I am not sure but I doubt the above code would work for that. It is still going to copy the formulas but then sets the value of the cell as the formula result.