# Save as Excel with same format, but no formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a code that extracts a tab from a workbook and saves the tab as a separate sheet. Everything is working fine for me, except for the fact that the formulas are also extracted to the new sheet. How can I change the code mentioned below to save the sheet in the same format, but without any formulas?

```
Sub PrintFile2()

'check if folder exists
If Dir("C:\Excel Workpaper\", vbDirectory) = "" Then
MkDir "C:\Excel Workpaper\"
End If

'print to defined folder
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim wb As Workbook
Sheets("Calculations").Copy
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

With wb
.SaveAs "C:\Excel Workpaper\ " & Range("B7").Text & " - Excel Workpaper", 
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

.Close False
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If i understood your question you can read this post... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981582/copy-values-no-formulas-excel-vba hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Check this snippet, this code will change formula to values.

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sh.Select
        With sh.UsedRange
            .Cells.Copy
            .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Cells(1).Select
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next sh
```